# SQLite UPDATE не меняет

Tags: android, sqlite

Никак не могу разобраться с sqlite запросом update в android

```
String query3 = "UPDATE Result SET dostup = '1' WHERE _id = '18'";
    sdb.rawQuery(query3, null);

String query4 = "SELECT dostup FROM Result WHERE _id='18'";
    Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery(query4, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int dostupnew = c.getInt(0);
```

Стартовое значение 0, так и остается, хотя код должен поменять значение на 1.

Где косяк?

Comment: Попробуйте зафиксировать транзакции ручками. Либо получить курсор на query3 и закрыть его ([здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982663) пишут, что перед закрытием надо еще, например, `moveToFirst` вызвать).

Comment: Тип поля `_id` - `Integer`, а вы даете ему `String`

Comment: @Barmaley, а это имеет значение? [Здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/80abe/3) вроде все работает

Comment: @ВОРОН, вы правы - еще раз проверил на своей локальной копии - все работает и так. Значит остается только версия с транзакциями

Answer (score 2):

Замените rawQuery на execSQL:

```
sdb.execSQL(query3);
```

rawQuery не выполняет запрос, пока нет движения по курсору, который она возвращает. А update курсор не возвращает вовсе, поэтому вызывать moveToFirst() - это какой-то хак.

ЗЫ А вообще логичнее использовать [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

Comment: `rawQuery не выполняет запрос, пока нет движения по курсору, который она возвращает` - а пруф на это есть? Вроде все объясняет, но в [доках](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) это не написано: `Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.`

Comment: Кстати, про `execSQL` в тех же доках пишут: `Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.`

Comment: @BOPOH, во-первых, по вашей ссылке на SO тоже об этом говорят (в другом ответе). во-вторых, можно посмотреть исходники: курсор создается для prepared query и все, fillWindow не происходит пока не будет вызван move. Курсор для не select запросов создается суррогатный, видимо для защиты от дурака, не читающего доки, где написано пользуйтесь update. Да, вы правы, то же написано и про execSQL, т.к. он в основном предназначен для DDL запросов, но работать будет без побочных эффектов как с rawQuery.

Comment: Сорри, чуть в другом вопросе о том же было http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855448